# How to build and deploy a react-native app from command line?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, fastlane

I'd like to automate the build + deploy of my React-Native app, for example to submit a TestFlight build.

Before submitting the app, I usually do the following:

1. I run `react-native bundle`
2. I switch the build configuration to `Release` in the schema
3. I comment out the code relative to `jsCodeLocation` in AppDelegate.m

Is it possible to write a single command from the Terminal for doing those steps, so that I can then deploy it with an automatization tool, e.g. with `fastlane`?

So far, I'd just need to automatize the 2nd and the 3rd step.

To change `jsCodeLocation` I could add a condition, e.g.

```
#if "<build configuration is release>"
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
#else 
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#end
```

but i don't know how to reach the build configuration setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I solved rewriting `AppDelegate.m` as

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle"];
#else
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
```

now i can use fastlane to deploy without editing the file.

Comment: Just saying, the app is the client side, not the server side, so the hostname `0.0.0.0` will make the debug version not working. (Although you can modify it in the app's debug menu)