# How to build .ipa for React Native?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, command-line, ipa

I come to React Native development without previous experience in iOS development. I want to build release. .ipa file - ideally from the command line but the official documentation [Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#content) is very brief.

I was able to deploy applications on my iPhone manually via XCode but still, I can't find any "release IPA" file. I have updated my code with `#ifdef DEBUG` directives to make it more generic.

Is there a way to build an application in release mode only via the command-line? If no, what is "the official" way to generate an RN application?

I am currently using RN 0.20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build and deploy a react-native app from command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885433/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-react-native-app-from-command-line)

Comment: as I already mention I already use `#ifdef` trick. Unfortunatelly the other question does not mention how to build it (except that it was possible with `fastlane`).

Answer (score 52):

First, you need to create a bundle this way :

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Then, you have to comment this line in AppDelegate.m :

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

and uncomment this one :

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

Then you have to go for Product -> Archive in Xcode and follow the steps based on your desired release

Comment: do you know where in the archive I can find .ipa file?

Comment: Once you archive, you can save your IPA file if I recall well. From the pop-up window that appears when your archive build succeeds.

Comment: in XCode 7.2.1 it just produced directory with several files but no IPA file.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573321/specify-location-for-ipa-file-in-xcode-7-ad-hoc-release)

Comment: 1. I have no IPA file on my computer (`find / -name "*.ipa" -print`) 2. Archive option has not further steps, it just create `.xcarchive` folder

Comment: To note, if Product > Archive is unavailable, make sure you have "Generic iOS Device" selected as your destination, and not one of the simulators.

Comment: You need to be registered as an apple developer to create a `.ipa`, Then go to Product > Archive > Export... However, this answered my question as to how to actually create a production build, so thank you very much G. Hamaide

Comment: How to do this on windows? There is no xcode on windows.

Comment: Should be "--platform ios" not "--platform iOS". "iOS" will result in error "Unrecognised platform"

Comment: I have only this string in AppDelegate.m: jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil]; What should I comment/uncomment?

Comment: I am run your command, it will say 'Assets destination folder is not set, skipping..' and I am not able to load image.

Comment: @G.Hamaide Do you know how to do your approach using command line without opening XCode?

Comment: This answer is out of date - current versions of RN have a custom shell script in the xcode build process that automatically runs the bundling for you, so this is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 20):

You have to set Scheme to Release.

From docs you have two ways.

> To do this, go to Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme (cmd + <), make sure you're in the Run tab from the side, and set the Build Configuration dropdown to Release.

or

> You can also use the React Native CLI to perform this operation using the option --configuration with the value Release (e.g. react-native run-ios --configuration Release).

Then you can generate your archive as usual.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#building-your-app-for-production

Comment: This is the correct updated answer, the others are old

Comment: @jperelli this command is for running on simulator , it will launch a simulator, and the product is 'Release-iphonesimulator', not 'Release-iphoneos'.

Comment: this is answer how to run, not how to build. everyone in react community seems to mistake these two things

Answer (score 13):

i cannot comment on the above answer,
it is correct but you need to start with the following command in order for it to work:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

the difference is 'ios'  instead of 'iOS'

if not it will  give the following error:

```
ProjectPath/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
  throw err;
  ^
```

Comment: Which answer are you responding to? "above" is relative