# How to generate .ipa file for react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently using React-Native version 0.40.0.

Can somebody give me a link on the process and steps on how to generate an .ipa file for ios?? I'm currently new to react-native.

Btw I'm using version 8 of Xcode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build .IPA for React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476349/how-to-build-ipa-for-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Following

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

If you do not have a platform variant of index.js, then change the command to target your single index.js:

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Comment: How does this build the `.ipa` file and where is it stored?

Comment: there is no index.ios.js file

Comment: @Kasra this is 3 years old answer. i have to check again. i will check and update my answer. thanks for point out

Comment: @SantoshSharma After I ran that, I ran find . -name "*.ipa" and there is no ipa file :(.

Comment: @DeanHiller sorry for that...this is 3 years old answer. i have to check again. i will check and update my answer. thanks for point out

Answer (score 0):

Open `projectname.xcworkspace` from `ios` folder in Xcode.

Build app by going to `Product` -> `Build`

Archive app by going to `Product` -> `Archive'
[image]

Once both `Build` and `Archive` are successful, it will trigger an option to distribute app.

[image]

Select `Development` option in second step and select default options in all next steps, it will generate ipa file. Airdrop or transfer this `ipa` file to any ios device and test app.
[image]
[image]
Make sure you are logged in to user accounts using apple id.

Answer (score -1):

**Get .app file : Run this command ->  react-native run-ios --configuration=release**

**Convert .app to .ipa :**

1. Create folder Payload.
2. paste .app file into Payload folder.
3. compress the Payload folder.
4. change the name you want and put extension as .ipa.

Comment: Doesn't work. `An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):`

Comment: The **.ipa** needs to be signed in order to upload to **App Store Connect**.