# How to get offline bundling of iOS in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Anyone could you please explain how to generate offline bundle of iOS application from 'react native' code?

I have already tried [How to generate .ipa file for react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970435/how-to-generate-ipa-file-for-react-native) but it is not working.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
react-native run-ios --configuration=release
```

Will run your app on Simulator or Device with the bundle.

Or just build it from Xcode (release build always includes the bundle)
Or run the debug release but before that, you should :

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Also, new react-native versions index.ios.js not found because of we need run this,

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Comment: How to enable the debug release? Is it `scheme > build configuration > release`?

Comment: @StanislavMayorov If you wanna debug a release build, better to have crash reporting like Sentry.io

Comment: If you get an error that main.jsbundle does not exist after running `react-native run-ios --configuration Release`, make sure that you do not have any whitespace characters in your project path. The bundler command does not handle whitespace characters well. So change a project path like `/users/bob/project world domination` to `/users/bob/project-world-domination`

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming you wish to run the app on a ios device without deploying it into the app store.
If that is the case then:

First I would make sure I have `ios-deploy` installed.

You can do so by running `npm install -g ios-deploy`

Then connect the iphone you want the app to be installed in into your mac.

Then run

```sh
react-native run-ios --device "XYZ’s iPhone" --configuration=release
```

This would create a offline js bundled app and install it onto the iphone.

*PS: If it errors out saying*

```
Signing for "<app name>" requires a development team. 
Select a development team in the project editor.
```

Then open up the project inside `ios/` in Xcode and 
Select the target -> General Tab
Under signing choose the signing team and choose automatically manage signing.

Then save and re-run the command.

Comment: after doing this, when i went back to development, and run my project, my metro bundle is not loading.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

Step one:

```
react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Step two:

```
react-native run-ios --configuration=release
```

This worker for me.

Method 2
use xcode and change debug to release, like this:
[image]

Comment: method 1 did not work for me. It just created the bundle, started the simulator, and threw an error "No Bundle URL present"