# How to build react native .app application into .ipa application?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

How to build react native .ipa application in mac os.

I would try "react-native run-ios --configuration=release" but that can generate .app file format.

Source : "[how to get offline bunduling of ios in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091721/how-to-get-offline-bunduling-of-ios-in-react-native)"

So how to build stand alone .ipa application?

Comment: try following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970435/how-to-generate-ipa-file-for-react-native/41970662#41970662

Comment: Yeah I would try that also following statements displayed in terminal.

bundle: Writing bundle output to: ios/main.jsbundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
Assets destination folder is not set, skipping...

But I can't get .ipa file. @santhosh Sharma

Comment: Convert .app to .ipa :

       1. Create folder Payload.

       2. paste .app file into Payload folder.

       3. compress the Payload folder.

       4. change the name you want and put extension as .ipa.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Convert .app to .ipa :**

1. Create folder Payload.
2. paste .app file into Payload folder.
3. compress the Payload folder.
4. change the name you want and put extension as .ipa.