# react native how to generate .ipa file from window

Tags: xcode, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I would try  ["How to generate .ipa file for react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970435/how-to-generate-ipa-file-for-react-native)" But I don't have mac laptop

i want to generate .ipa file from react-native project  on  windows 
to test it on my iphone device 
so is it possible to generate ipa from window without xcode

Comment: you cannot create ipa from windows machine because ipa will only generate from xcode.

Answer (score 0):

there is no possible way to create IPA file from windows but you can install virtual box and run IOS.

Comment: i try it did not work do you have a guaranteed way to install mac os on VB ??

Comment: i follow this video instruction but it did not work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxNCIw8LP2Q