# How to generate standalone react-native app for simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to generate standalone react-native application for a iPhone simulator. 
I am able run it on my machine via Xcode, but it automatically start `./node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js start` and it loads js files into app.

It is possible to generate `*.app` with js files?

I use this command: `xcodebuild -workspace "ios/MyApp.xcworkspace" -scheme "MyApp" -sdk iphonesimulator -destination='name=iPhone 6,OS=10.3' build -derivedDataPath ios/build`

and I got this error after launch application:

`May  2 16:59:21 MacMini MyApp[15965]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'bundleURL must be non-nil when not implementing loadSourceForBridge'
    *** First throw call stack:`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your app within Xcode, I believe following the link below will help.

(see answer by G. Hamaide)

[How to build .IPA for React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476349/how-to-build-ipa-for-react-native)

Comment: *.ipa is only for real devices and it doesn't work for simulator. Or am I wrong?